# Scrollview is centered and crams content on first time contents show [SwiftUI]

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have built a scrollview that is populated after an API call is successful. The issue i am facing is after the first time content is populated all the listings are crammed onto the center of the screen. It is only after i close the view and reopen it that i see the proper listings properly fit on the screen. I have no idea, i've tried to readjust the frame with no luck.

The fact that when i navigate away and back then the view corrects itself is what's confusing me, had it been maintaining the same behavior it would be easily understandable

```
  ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
            if(searchResultsViewModel.listings.count == 0){
                ActivityIndicator().foregroundColor(Color(hex:Global.colorAccent))
                                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30).padding(EdgeInsets(top: 15,leading: 0,bottom: 0,trailing: 0))

            }else {
            ForEach(self.searchResultsViewModel.listings, id: \.self){ item in
                           HStack(spacing: 0) {
                               ForEach(item, id: \.self) { listing in
                               NavigationLink(destination: ListingDetailsView(listing: listing)) {
                                   ListingView(listing: listing)
                                   }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                               }
                           }
                       }
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle(title)
```

Below is an image of what im trying to explain

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to force rebuild scrollview, because original does not know that content size changed.

So assuming `self.searchResultsViewModel` is observed view model

```
@State private var scrollViewID = UUID()    // << initial

// ... other code

    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){

    // ... content here

    }.id(scrollViewID)                 // << dynamic id 
    .navigationBarTitle(title)
    .onReceive(self.searchResultsViewModel.$listings) { _ in
        self.scrollViewID = UUID()     // << force rebuild
    }
```

Comment: This does the trick. I am wondering why though because i have a similar interface when the user starts the app but the same thing doesn't happen. Only happens on this search implementation